# How can I determine whether two simple graphs are isomorphic using matrices?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, discrete-mathematics

I think you have to swap between columns and again for rows but it didn't work so does any one have any solution?

Note: one of the matrices is static and the other variable.

[image: Example]

Comment: please check the photo to see what i talk about

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm, or need help with its implementation? Also, I'm sure there are math packages out there where the algorithm is already implemented.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev yes i need the algorithm

Comment: For educational purposes or for real life problems?

Comment: for educational purposes @SevaAlekseyev

Answer (score 3):

It is [unknown whether this problem is in the class P](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc). Thus it is extremely unlikely you will find a reasonable-time solution for it.  If you do, you should publish it.

Given that, you can basically just go over all permutations of rows and columns for one of the matrices, and check to see if the result of any is the second matrix.